# Match data iteratively with SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm struggling with a query, and I've been stuck for a couple of days without figuring out if this is even possible.

I have a resultset like the following:

```
ID  ;CASE;LINE;QTY;ORDER;CODE
1446;2725;   1;  1;33333;A
1446;2724;   1;  1;33333;A
0430;2545;   1;  2;44444;B
0430;2547;   1;  2;44444;B
9628;2710;   1;  1;55555;C
9628;2708;   1;  1;55555;C
9628;2708;   2;  1;66666;
9628;2710;   2;  1;66666;
9628;2710;   3;  1;55555;C
9628;2708;   3;  1;55555;C
```

From those lines, I want to get these:

```
1446;2725;   1;  1;33333;A
1446;2724;   1;  1;33333;A
0430;2545;   1;  2;44444;B
0430;2547;   1;  2;44444;B
9628;2710;   1;  1;55555;C
9628;2708;   3;  1;55555;C
```

Or:

```
1446;2725;   1;  1;33333;A
1446;2724;   1;  1;33333;A
0430;2545;   1;  2;44444;B
0430;2547;   1;  2;44444;B
9628;2708;   1;  1;55555;C
9628;2710;   3;  1;55555;C
```

, i.e., I want to filter out the ones with CODE null (I can do that) and want to match cases with lines (this is where I'm having problems).

The thing is that I don't have any relation to discriminate. It doesn't matter that CASE 2708 is matched to LINE 3 or 1, but CASE 2710 needs to be matched to a different LINE.

This would be very easy in a language like Java or C++, but since I cannot declare variables or lists, I don't know how to "mark" a LINE as selected.

I cannot use stored procedures too. I'm starting to think is not possible to accomplish, but maybe someone can throw a bit of light.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what "CASE 2710 needs to be matched to a different LINE" means.  2710 is associated with line 1, 2, and 3, and you want it to bring back 1 or 3 but not 2?  Why??

Comment: Is it fair to translate that to: I want unique combinations of `(case, line)` only?

Comment: @Julien, I don't want to match with 2 because CODE is null. I want 2708 to match with either 1 or 3, and 2710 with the other possibility.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, not sure. Initially I have four unique combinations, haven't I? [(2710,1), (2710,3), (2708,1), (2708,3)] I need to come up with either [(2710,1), (2708,3)] or [(2710,3), (2708,1)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit

First version did not address question.

`order` and `case` are [reserved words in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Do not use them as identifiers! I renamed to `ord` and `cas` in my example.

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT id, qty, ord, code
          ,min(line) AS line1
          ,max(line) AS line2
          ,min(cas)  AS cas1
          ,max(cas)  AS cas2
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE  code IS NOT NULL
    GROUP  BY 1,2,3,4
    )
SELECT id, cas1, line2, qty, ord, code
FROM   x
UNION  ALL  -- only add more rows, where 
SELECT id, cas2, line1, qty, ord, code
FROM   x
WHERE  cas1 <> cas2 AND line1 <> line2
ORDER  BY code, 1,2,3,4,5;
```

This assumes a maximum of two different `line` or `cas` per `code` and that other columns do not add more variations.
It produces the result demonstrated in the question.

Comment: This will produce all 4 combinations of cas(2708,2710) and line(1,3) - OP has said he only wants 2 with complementary values, ie. either 2708,1 and 2710,3, or 2708,3 and 2710,1.

Comment: @Mark: I answered along my pending request for clarification. But now that you point it out, it becomes clear to me what the OP wants. Will amend my answer shortly, thank you. (Edited to clean up.)

Comment: Would be possible to extend for a case of N different line or cas per code?

Comment: @Gothmog: With `n > 2` you need a more complex solution. You would need to define the problem exactly. This question was aimed at pairs of values (`n = 2`) judging from the examples. I would suggest you start a new question with an exact description if you want `n > 2`. Much is possible with pure SQL, but it can get very complex. Depending on the actual definition of the problem a plpgsql function might be a simpler / faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following will produce the same output as specified, although it isn't clear whether your data will always produce pairs of values by ID:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE M.AGG WHEN "MIN" THEN MIN(M."CASE")
            ELSE MAX(M."CASE")
       END AS "CASE",
       CASE M.AGG WHEN "MIN" THEN MIN(M.LINE)
            ELSE MAX(M.LINE)
       END AS LINE,
       CASE M.AGG WHEN "MIN" THEN MIN(M.QTY)
            ELSE MAX(M.QTY)
       END AS QTY,
       CASE M.AGG WHEN "MIN" THEN MIN(M."ORDER")
            ELSE MAX(M."ORDER")
       END AS "ORDER",
       CASE M.AGG WHEN "MIN" THEN MIN(M."CODE")
            ELSE MAX(M."CODE")
       END AS "CODE"
FROM MYTABLE M
CROSS JOIN (SELECT "MIN" AGG UNION SELECT "MAX") A
WHERE M.CODE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY M.ID, A.AGG
```